# Problem with Quick.DB/better-sqlite3 install script

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm-install

I'm using Quick.DB as a database for fetching and sending data for my discord.js bot. However, when I try installing my dependencies, it returns me this error while it installs better-sqlite3 specifically for Quick.DB. It tries to compile the install script to create binding files but after a while it returns me this error. I'm using [repl.it](https://replit.com/) for coding this bot as I find it flexible.

```
> better-sqlite3@7.1.5 install /home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node)

> better-sqlite3@7.1.5 build-release /home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release

make: Entering directory '/home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
  TOUCH b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_locate_sqlite3_target_extract_sqlite3 b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/locate_sqlite3.stamp
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
deps/sqlite3.target.mk:183: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite3/sqlite3.o] Error 4
rm b857c92884e9598d609f6be182a2595df7a8e00f.intermediate
make: Leaving directory '/home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1042-gcp
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/runner/azeliav2-2/node_modules/better-sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.5 build-release: `node-gyp rebuild --release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.5 build-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-05-02T03_56_51_256Z-debug.log
[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:[            ......] | install: info lifecycle better-sqlite3@7.1.5~install:npm WARN hello-express@0.0.1 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! better-sqlite3@7.1.5 install: `prebuild-install || npm run build-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the better-sqlite3@7.1.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-05-02T03_56_52_435Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answer that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67388739/15035986).
GLIBC_2.29 not found error is causing outdated libc6 package. You would need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

more about that on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

But you would need **sudo** privileges. You do not have sudo privileges on repl.it.

You should not use quick.db anyway on repl.it, because on repl.it all users information will public - this is against discord terms of service.

> Repl.it's limitation is that you cannot hide files from the public eye
> on free accounts, except for the .env file. This means, if you were to
> use a file-based or sqlite-based database (such as enmap, quick.db,
> nedb) your files would be visible. Since this is against the Discord
> Terms of Service (exposing potential user data), do not use these
> modules or json files to store data. Instead, you can use the Repl.It
> Database system to store data, or an external database server like
> Atlas Mongo, or Firebase.
> [anidiots.guide](https://anidiots.guide/hosting/repl)