# How to fix quick.db is not installing?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, replit, quick.db

I have been trying to install quick.db package on my repl.it project but on every time I try that it just crashes and gives this error:
[image]

It was working fine before but when I reinstalled it for a reason it started crushing every time. I need this package to store information and no other packages I try with the same function work good for me. Please suggest another package or help me install quick.db.

Comment: How is this related to javascript? Java? Discord.js? Bots?

Comment: It is a javascript application and it is a bot for discord

Comment: There's no JavaScript to debug, just because it's in the context of a discordjs bot does not mean its related to DJS. At the very least this is related to quick.db and npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLIBC_2.29 not found error is causing outdated libc6 package. You would need to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

more about that on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

But you would need sudo privileges. You do not have sudo privileges on repl.it.

You should not use quick.db anyway on repl.it, because on repl.it all users information will public - this is against discord terms of service.

> Repl.it's limitation is that you cannot hide files from the public eye
> on free accounts, except for the .env file. This means, if you were to
> use a file-based or sqlite-based database (such as enmap, quick.db,
> nedb) your files would be visible. Since this is against the Discord
> Terms of Service (exposing potential user data), do not use these
> modules or json files to store data. Instead, you can use the Repl.It
> Database system to store data, or an external database server like
> Atlas Mongo, or Firebase.
> [anidiots.guide](https://anidiots.guide/hosting/repl)

Comment: Dude it says bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: @Hassan_BH you do not have sudo privileges on repl.it you would know that if you read my answer.

Comment: How can I get them on repl.it, the package got installed before but now IDK what happened

Comment: They probably updated something - i think they introduced repl.it database and they discontinued support for this type of databases. https://docs.replit.com/misc/database 
you can store your data in repl.it database, which is not public.

Comment: this might also help you - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@replit/database

Comment: Thanks for help, I used there database and it works great. even if they don't have `db.add`
but I figured I can use `db.set(value, value+ <the amount I want to add>)`.